# Adding a link to wordpress admin posts page

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and i just  want to add a link to the posts page in the back end , like the one that appears when someone has set a post as sticky.This link  will redirect someone to a specific category of posts in the back end .How can I achieve this?

[link position here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRA8X.jpg)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you describe your problem in details?

Comment: check this
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/

Comment: @KrupalPanchal The owner of the website does not want the sticky posts to remain on the home page because someone is constantly forced to scroll to see the new posts. So I decided to put a slider and in it to put the posts that correspond to a new category of permanent articles .Link sticky disappeared as shown in the photo.In its place I want to put a link that leads to the category permanent articles.I know I can do it if I choose from the combobox categories the category permanent articles, but the owner would like a link in  place there was the sticky  link.